# Unity3D position of 2D objects with size of Object

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, scale

I'm making a 2D project in Unity3D.
I want to place an image in the right upper corner.
I've got this working, but ofcourse the image is falling of the screen for a part (and completely when I change the screenrotation).

[image]

This is the code I've got for it;

```
posImage = new Vector2(Screen.width - imgGear.transform.localScale.x, Screen.height - imgGear.transform.lossyScale.y );
```

As you can see in the code I've tried to adapt the position with the size of the object, using localScale 1.0f and lossyscale 0.9...f doesn't really do much as it will be changed with 1 unit.
Is their a way to get the real width and height of the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same problem for atleast 2 week until i figured myself how to handle object in different resolution which **preventing object falling apart** or place object based with the screen resolution .

***If you want to keep the object right in the position following camera , don't forget to put the object inside camera object .***

this is my script to control the resolution :

**calculateresolution.cs**

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class calculateresolution : MonoBehaviour {

    // change this to resolution size when you create the game 
        
 float desiredscreenheights = 768;
 float desiredscreenwidths = 1366;


void CalculateResolution(string theobjectm) {
 GameObject objecttocalculate = GameObject.Find(theobjectm);
 float desiredscreenheight = desiredscreenheights;
 float desiredscreenwidth = desiredscreenwidths;
 float desiredaspectratiowidth = desiredscreenwidth / desiredscreenheight;
 float desiredaspectratioheight = desiredscreenheight / desiredscreenwidth ;
 float screenheight = Screen.height;
 float screenwidth = Screen.width;
 float aspectratioheight = screenheight / screenwidth;
 float aspectratiowidth = screenwidth / screenheight;
 Debug.Log (screenheight + " " + screenwidth + " " + aspectratioheight + " " + aspectratiowidth);
 float objectsizex = objecttocalculate.transform.localScale.x;
 float objectsizey = objecttocalculate.transform.localScale.y;
 float objectsizez = objecttocalculate.transform.localScale.z;
 float objectcoordx = objecttocalculate.transform.localPosition.x;
 float objectcoordy = objecttocalculate.transform.localPosition.y;
 float objectcoordz = objecttocalculate.transform.localPosition.z;
 Debug.Log (objectsizex + " " + objectsizey + " " + objectsizez + " " + objectcoordx + " " + objectcoordy + " " + objectcoordz);
 float newobjectsizex = aspectratiowidth / desiredaspectratiowidth * objectsizex;
 float newobjectsizey = objectsizey;
 float newobjectsizez = objectsizez;
 float newobjectcoordx = aspectratiowidth / desiredaspectratiowidth * objectcoordx;
 float newobjectcoordy = aspectratiowidth / desiredaspectratiowidth * objectcoordy;
 float newobjectcoordz = objectcoordz;
 Debug.Log (newobjectsizex + " " + newobjectsizey + " " + newobjectsizez);
 Debug.Log (newobjectcoordx + " " + newobjectcoordy + " " + newobjectcoordz);
 objecttocalculate.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (newobjectsizex, newobjectsizey, newobjectsizez);
 objecttocalculate.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (newobjectcoordx, newobjectcoordy, newobjectcoordz);
 Debug.Log ("Calculate Finish For Now");




}
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
// your gameobject name 
     
CalculateResolution ("yourobjectname ");
}       
 
}
```

To calculate the object , just call CalculateResolution("**yourgameobjectname**") , change **yourgameobjectname** with the **object name** .

Change "**float desiredscreenwidths**" and "**float desiredscreenheights**" value to resolution size you use to build the game .

***But unfortunally this script does not support screen rotation because i did not know how to :I sorry , or maybe you tell me how ;) .***

Comment: EDIT : adding new method

Comment: This is a rather long code :p
For the rotating aspect, you've manually filled in the screen resolution.
If you fill in screen.width and screen.height instead of the numbers, wouldn't that automatically adapt when screen is rotated?
I will put this code in my test environment and check if it gives me some nice output.

Comment: okay ;) oh yes im trying to make it work for screen rotation but i did not yet figured how

Comment: for screen rotation it's used screen.orientation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html but i still learning the function

Comment: I've ran the code and figured it's not like 100 what i was looking for, but it gave me a hint and I think I found the reason why it doesn't work :)
When screen is horizontal is calculates the size (1f, i'll have to deal with it)
but when rotating it will still be positioned as before since it doesn't reposition on rotating screen. :)
I'll have to use a function that if it's rotated the screen will reposition.

Comment: well goodluck with scaling angle ;) because im trying too here , also in 2d you don't ever need to rotate camera i guess :)

Comment: Moved from start() to update() ! :) thanks for the solution !

Comment: It is happy to see that the script worked for you :) because im really - beginner to unity :p well if there any more problem , just tell me :) i will answer ( if i know ) .

Comment: if you use `RectTransform rt = image.GetComponent<RectTransform>();`
`rt.rect.width` or `rt.rect.height`you will get the width and height in pixels

Answer (score 1):

When I putted the positioning script in the update part instead of the start function, it changed position perfectly when rotating screen.
For the "real size" of the object I might have to puzzle a bit.

I know that repositioning on every update can be causing some lag in the application but since it is a menu screen, it doesn't cause mayor delays in the application (menu's and popups still open instantly).

this is how i got it now :) [image]